# Connecting to the Database on client side

Tags: sql, sql-server, connection-string, mdf

I am working on a standalone desktop application. I am Using an `mdf file` for the database and I have two connection strings

```
Server =.\SQLExpress;
AttachDbFilename = C:\MyFolder\MyDataFile.mdf;
Database = dbname; 
Trusted_Connection = Yes;
```

I don't want to use this string because its not necessary that the client will install it on same path

```
Server =.\SQLExpress;
AttachDbFilename =|Directory\MyDataFile.mdf;
Database = dbname;
Trusted_Connection = Yes;
```

and this shows

> **error 40:** Unable to connect sql server when installed on clients PC

Answer (score 0):

You need to store in variable entire connection string, it'll work.

If it don't, please share your code that acquire connection.